# Python AZ translate The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Python 3.8.3 and try to use Azure Translation. Based on the example of (https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cognitive-services/Translator/quickstart-translate?pivots=programming-language-python) I try to re-create the example for myself and minimized the code.

[image]

I create an Azure Resource (Translate) and copied the **key** and the **endpoint** in the code. But when I run the code, I get the following error:

> "code": 401000,
> "message": "The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."

Can someone please explain what i doing wrong and how to fix this issue!

I use this code:

```
import os, requests, uuid, json

path = '/translate?api-version=3.0'
params = '&to=de&to=it'
constructed_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com" + path + params

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

# You can pass more than one object in body.
body = [{
    'text' : 'Hello World!'
}]
request = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Many thanks
Erik

Comment: Could the error be that there is a `//` in the url between the base-URL and `path`?

Comment: What I mean is that it should maybe be this: `"https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com" + path + params` It's a small change, but it would drastically change the path to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! It does not mather for the response.Have you other ideas ?

Comment: In the documentation you've linked it says this: `If you are using a Cognitive Services multi-service subscription, you must also include the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region in your request parameters`. If that's what you're using, then you might have to provide that in the `headers` variable as well.

Comment: I use indeed  "TextAnalytics", "Translator", "Cognitive Service" but what need i to fill in all the keys?

Comment: Okay, then please try to add `"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region": "api-eur.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com",` to the `headers` variable and see of that solves it. Or whatever region that matches your subscription.

Comment: Thanks that works! Realy strange that they don't put that in the examples!

Comment: Glad, I could help. I have deleted my comment and expanded the answer. The reason being that it is not included in the examples may be because there is a  assumption that it is simple out of box cognitive service (not multiservice) :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#authentication), since you are using multiple services. It is a must to include the 2 authentication headers with your request.

```
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key   The value is the Azure secret key for your multi-service resource.

Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region    The value is the region of the multi-service resource.
```

Location here is the specified Subscription Region.

Looking through your screenshot. It appears that region to be - **westeurope**

**Updated Headers for your use case :**

```
headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region' : 'westeurope',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}
```